# I can't create a new Angular project

Tags: angular

when I try this in order to create a new project in a concrete folder

```
ng new open-events-front –-style=scss --prefix=oevents
```

Angular says to me:

Unknown option: '–-style'

Why does it fail?.

My Angular version is 10.0.8.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a different hyphen next to `style` (the first `–`):

```
–-style=scss
^
here

--style=scss
```

Try this:

```
ng new open-events-front --style=scss --prefix=oevents
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to that. Just try this:

```sh
ng new app-name
```

Angular CLI ask you about the `Style`, `Routing` and others during generating your project.

Comment: The CLI does not ask about the prefix.